# Facebook Graph API - Postback Event Issue

Tags: node.js, facebook-graph-api, botframework

There is a problem when the user is clicking a postback button and the internet connection is not stable or is reconnecting from the internet. After reconnecting to the internet, it will look like the user has successfully clicked the button (Labeled as Sent) but my webhook is not getting any postback events. So the user does not get any response from my bot unless they click the button again with a stable connection.

I already sent a [support ticket](https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/217964392185699/?disable_redirect=0) to Facebook regarding this. I'm asking help for a workaround this issue, that will continue the conversation or maybe a reminder that the user must click the button again to progress.

I'm using Node.js and Microsoft Bot Framework for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I am unfamiliar with Facebook Messenger for bots, as far as I can tell, a postback button seems to work the same as any other button, with added async functionality. The intermittent internet connection appears to be interrupting that async call. There isn't a work around that I know of, as your bot is still waiting for a response from your user, a response that won't come, if your user thinks they've already sent info to the bot.

I would put a proactive/welcome message in the very beginning of your bot dialog that if the user is connecting with a weak/intermittent internet connection, to resend their response if the bot doesn't respond. If you're using the bot for sales purposes, then a message to not use the bot unless they're using a stable internet connection as they could accidentally send a purchase order twice, would be more appropriate.